# Trusted sites, JQuery-UI dialogs, Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I think i have a strange problem. 
I add my site to trusted sites in IE (version 9 and 10). 
All security settings are low, active scripting etc. is activated, so all normal JavaScript functions running correctly. We use also jQueryUI for dialog windows, but the windows will not display. No JavaScript error returns. If i enable the active scripting for all sites, the windows are created correctly.

I hope somebody has an solution or some tips or trick about this.

I added the jQueryUI homepage to my trusted sites for testing too, and i can reproduce the effect on the dialog demo on this page with my browser (high security settings for all sites and lowest security settings for trusted sites). 
Perhaps someone can tell me, what do I wrong.

The following code is a part of my JavaScript library for creating a dialog window. After a successful ajax request I create the dialog-window with some content from the ajax-request.

```
success: function (data) {
    var diagWidth = 1000;
    var diagHeight = 500;
    $('#dialog_window_3').html('');
    $('#dialog_window_3').html(data);
    $('#dialog_window_3').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'My Title',
        width: diagWidth,
        height: diagHeight,
        position: {
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            of: window
        },
        closeOnEscape: true,
        draggable: true,
        buttons: {
            'close': function () {
                $('#dialog_window_3').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    closeWaitingWindow();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: Are you loading any of your js libraries from a different host?